# Plotting a variable measured monthly with a variable measured yearly in the same plot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here are two samples of datasets I would like to plot together on the same plot:

```
>head(df1)
   Date                 y
1 2015-10-01        6217.734
2 2015-09-01        6242.592
3 2015-08-01        6772.145
4 2015-07-01        6865.719
```

and

```
>head(df2)
  Year           x
1 1980          5760
2 1981          4765
3 1982          2620
4 1983          7484
```

Given that `df2$Year` and `df1$Date` overlap date ranges and `df1$y` and `df2$x` are of the same scale, how can I best plot `y` and `x` against time on the same plot given that `x` is measured only yearly and `y` monthly?

I imagine it will require converting `Year` to an arbitrary date (`1980-01-01, 1981-01-01`). But beyond that, other than altering my `df2` data.frame to having twelve observations per year with the same `x` value per observation, then combining the two data.frames, I cannot think of what to do.

I would prefer to use `ggplot2` if there is a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out for me?

`library(dygraphs)`

`library(xts)`

rename one of your variable to match the other scaled variable

rename Year to match the other's date

then do

```
prep <-  cbind(df1, df2)

ts_object <-  as.xts(prep[,2:ncol(prep)], prep$Year)

dygraph(ts_object)
```

**Note that you are providing literally NO data for me to work with here. If you can do so that'd be great. Try using `dput(df1)`, and `dput(df2)`, and post the output of these commands**

Comment: The small sample I provided was meant to illustrate my situation, I didn't think it was really appropriate on here to put hundreds or even dozens of lines of data in a question. Regarding your answer, I get an error running the first line because the `data.frames` have different number of rows (over the same period 1980-2015, the monthly measured data has 12x as many rows). I will edit my question to try and make it more clear what I am asking.

Comment: Try converting Year to a Date and then use something like `merge(df1, df2, by = variables you choose)`, or `join(df1, df2)`

Does either of these combine it how you'd like?